# How to debug Razor Asp.Net anchor tag generation when using Controller and Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, razorgenerator

I am trying to learn Razor and Asp.Net, following a couple of courses. I see that this snippet of code should work, but the generated link is empty:

```
<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Course" asp-action="Index">Courses</a>
```

There is a `CourseController` with an `Index` action. In fact, Rider is even able to jump to their definition when I click on the attribute values.
Nevertheless, the generated anchor tag does not include a link, just the CSS style.

I tried to change the type of link to `asp-page`, trying to link into the  `index.cshtml` file I have inside a `Course` folder. But it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no default route. Adding this code to `Program.cs` seems to fix the issue:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```